# sshplus config file

Tags: ssh

I just recently lost my old hdd and put a new one in my machine and have been getting back to where I was before this whole mess and now I can't seem to find clear instructions on how to make a config file for sshplus, or where to find an example config file that I can just edit. Does anyone happen to know where I could find one?

Answer (score 0):

I found these instructions inside [sshplus.py](https://gist.github.com/kepler/1189327/download) file:

> 1. Copy `sshplus.py` file to `/usr/local/bin`
> 2. **Edit file `.sshplus` in your home directory to add menu entries, each line in the format:**
>
>    ```
>     NAME|COMMAND|ARGS
>    ```
> 3. Launch `sshplus.py`
> 4. Or better yet, add it to startup programs list so it's run on login.

Comment: I was also trying to find out how to make category separators and sub menus, any idea on those?